# Passing variable from nodejs to ejs file

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ejs

I have a variable that i want to pass from NodeJs to EJS file .
I need this variable to choose whether or not I display an alert().

while running my code i have "nbrow not defined"

server.js

```
con.query("SELECT * FROM entreprises WHERE identifiant =?",user, function (err, result) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log(result);
nbrow = result.length;
if(nbrow > 0)
{
    res.send("Connexion info :" + user + " " + password);    
}
else
{
    res.render("connexion",{ nbrow: nbrow});

}
});
```

connexion.ejs

```
   <script>
        if(<%= nbrow %> = 0){
            alert("user not exist");
        }
    </script>
```

I already searched on internet what could be wrong with my code but i found nothing that could help me.

my "if" is working fine same for my query and i'm connected to my database .

RE EDIT : someone asked me the view engine configuration, i don't really know what's that but i guess this is :

```
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing the error and does it have an accompanying stack trace or line number? Are you using any non-default EJS configuration options, such as `strict` mode? Do you have other EJS templates that are working fine in the same application? Have you restarted the server since you made the code changes? View changes are reloaded without a restart but other changes typically are not.

Comment: @skirtle When rendering the ejs without the <script> ....</script>  it's working fine . Once i add it , it show me the script as brut text in browser when i load the page . th error line is the same where the if Is . with always the same error message (see below) . i don't use strict mode and it's the only ejs i have actually and yes i restarted it loads of time .

Comment: Could you post the code you're using to configure the view engine?

Comment: i'll edit the code now

Comment: The code you've posted isn't the view engine, that's for static files. Static files won't interpret the template. You need to set the `views` and `view engine` settings. See https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html

Comment: @skirtle is it what i just edited ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using single `=` instead of `==`

It should be:

```
<script>
    if(<%= nbrow %> == 0){
        alert("user not exist");
    }
</script>
```

Also - regardless to this specific error.

EJS is rendered to html file, so in your browser you can always use 'view source' and see the actual rendered HTML. This way you can debug if the problem is in printing `nbrow` or the script.

Comment: saw it a couple minute ago , changed it but still the same issue , in my browser i don't see my html but that ;  <script>
    if(<%= nbrow %> == 0){
        alert("user not exist");
    }
</script> 
as brut text

Comment: If you see the actual <%= that means that your ejs file is not rendered at all.

Comment: WHEN i delete the <script> ..; </script> it's rendering

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the problem comes from this line :

```
nbrow = result.length;
```

This assumes that nbrow has already been defined elsewhere, but that's not the case, hence the `"nbrow is not defined"` error

Try to put `const` or `let` in front of it :

```
const nbrow = result.length;
```

Comment: it is defined above as var nbrow = 0;  tried to remove this line and replace it with const nbrow = result.length; but still not working same with "let"

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
 var nbrow = JSON.parse('<%- JSON.stringify(nbrow) %>');
 if(nbrow == 0)
     alert("user not exist");
 </script>
```

I do by stringify the variable and parse it back